# Multiple Visualization Libraries in One Project

Tags: charts, highcharts, vuejs3, visualization, amcharts

Is it feasible to incorporate multiple visualization tools and libraries within a single project, particularly when utilizing VueJS to integrate these charts as components, such as Amcharts, Highcharts, and ChartJS? I am inquiring about potential conflicts that may arise from using these diverse tools collectively. Thank you in advance

I am still using ChartJS as of the moment, and I want to use amcharts and highcharts too

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can have different visualization libraries with a single project.

Comment: But people try to stick to single libraries because of hassle of configurations aka Maintainability. If you want to achieve something complicated and want to change in multiple config files, to achieve same thing then its waste of time.

Comment: It would be helpful only if you doing it for learning or trying to run an experiment. Otherwise I personally wouldn't go for multiple libraries, unless one of it is providing features which I can't find or use in the current library.

Comment: This is also not good for website performance, more libraries means more data to download It is best to choose the one that offers the most functionality and options.